# a hrf link showing box and not showing Underline and bydefault Color

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, href

I have written this code to give href link to url. But the href link showing box which i dont want and not showing by default color and underline. Your help will be appreciated.
Thank You.
regards,
Rahul

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Support Portal</title>
        <style type="text/css">

                        .myTable {background-color:#D0D0D0 ;border-collapse:collapse;}
                        .myTable th {background-color:#BDB76B;color:white;}
                        .myTable td, .myTable th {padding:0.1px;border:1px solid #BDB76B;}


                </style>
    </head>
<?php
// -- REGISTER ERSTELLEN -------------------------------------------------------

$page['register'] = array(
            1   => array( 'Dashboard','aktiv',$page['script'],'',''),
        );

$page['doctype'] = true;
// -- BUTTON ERSTELLEN ---------------------------------------------------------
$page['button'] = array(
    0 => array( $ad_wort[$adl]['jetzt04s'],'pfeil2r','#','submitForm($(this).closest(\'form\'));return false;','',true),
);





// -- HTML AUSGEBEN ------------------------------------------------------------
$page['content'] .= '

<table width="538" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" >
<td>
    <div>'.CreateRegister($page['register']).'</div>
    '.CreateMessage().'
    <div class="cont-liste-verlauf register">

<table class="myTable" width="450" style="margin-top:10px; margin-left:-10px; float: left; ">

<td>
<p><a href="http://autodo/admin/amo_start.php?AlIn4aD2aM0201o" style="color:#69c"><font FACE="Arial" size="2"><strong>829 </strong> Anzahl Fahrzeuge mit und ohne Bilder</font></a></p><br> 
<p><a href="http://autodo/admin/amo_start.php?AlIn4aD2aM0201o" style="color:#69c"><font FACE="Arial" size="2"><strong>829 </strong> Fahrzeuge ohne Preis</font></a></p><br> 
<p><a href="http://autodo/admin/amo_start.php?AlIn4aD2aM0201o" style="color:#69c"><font FACE="Arial" size="2"><strong>829 </strong> Mit/ohne Preisschild</font></a></p><br> 
<p><a href="http://autodo/admin/amo_start.php?AlIn4aD2aM0201o" style="color:#69c"><font FACE="Arial" size="2"><strong>829 </strong> ohne GW-Siegel</font></a></p><br> 
<p><a href="http://autodo/admin/amo_start.php?AlIn4aD2aM0201o" style="color:#69c"><font FACE="Arial" size="2"><strong>829 </strong> Fahrzeuge ohne Importschutz</font></a></p><br> 
<p><a href="http://autodo/admin/amo_start.php?AlIn4aD2aM0201o" style="color:#69c"><font FACE="Arial" size="2"><strong>829 </strong> Fahrzeuge mit/ohne Dokumenten</font></a></p><br> 
<p><a href="http://autodo/admin/amo_start.php?AlIn4aD2aM0201o" style="color:#69c"><font FACE="Arial" size="2"><strong>829 </strong> Fahrzeuge mit Fehlern</font></a></p><br> 
<p><a href="http://autodo/admin/amo_start.php?AlIn4aD2aM0201o" style="color:#69c"><font FACE="Arial" size="2"><strong>829 </strong> Herausforderungen</font></a></p><br> 
<p><a href="http://autodo/admin/amo_start.php?AlIn4aD2aM0201o" style="color:#69c"><font FACE="Arial" size="2"><strong>829 </strong> Neueste Fahrzeuge</font></a></p><br> 
<p><a href="http://autodo/admin/amo_start.php?AlIn4aD2aM0201o" style="color:#69c"><font FACE="Arial" size="2"><strong>829 </strong> Reservierte Fahrzeuge</font></a></p><br> 
<p><a href="http://autodo/admin/amo_start.php?AlIn4aD2aM0201o" style="color:#69c"><font FACE="Arial" size="2"><strong>829 </strong> Bestellte Fahrzeuge</font></a></p><br> 
<p><a href="http://autodo/admin/amo_start.php?AlIn4aD2aM0201o" style="color:#69c"><font FACE="Arial" size="2"><strong>829 </strong> Fahrzeuge mit weniger als X Bilder</font></a></p><br> 
<p><a href="http://autodo/admin/amo_start.php?AlIn4aD2aM0201o" style="color:#69c"><font FACE="Arial" size="2"><strong>829 </strong> Anzahl Scans gesamt</font></a></p><br> 
<p><a href="http://autodo/admin/amo_start.php?AlIn4aD2aM0201o" style="color:#69c"><font FACE="Arial" size="2"><strong>829 </strong> Fahrzeuge ohne QR Code Aufkleber</font></a></p><br> 
<p><a href="http://autodo/admin/amo_start.php?AlIn4aD2aM0201o" style="color:#69c"><font FACE="Arial" size="2"><strong>829 </strong> Anzahl freie QR Code Aufkleber</font></a></p><br> 
</td>
</td>
</table>
</table>
</div>

';
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS for anchor tag:

```
a {
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

add styles whatever you want